# Mouse pointer missing in XGetImage()

Tags: c, image, x11, opencv3.0, xorg

When I use XGetImage() to take the image of a window, say the root window for example, the mouse pointer never occurs in the saved image (in .png format using opencv3).

So, is there a method to get the cursor also in the final image taken using XGetImage() (or any similar function in x11) ?
I didn't find any such function that does the job.

About XGetImage():
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html
I didn't find any such function that does the job.

Comment: The cursor may not even be part of the image but generated in hardware. If not, it's usually undesirable to include in an image, as its position may be arbitrary and it isn't even part of the image anyway.

Comment: Sir I didn't actually get by the phrase '... but generated in hardware'. Does that mean the cursor-concept is something very different from normal window concept, such that it always stays above all windows (including root window) ? Or something else?

Comment: It's a horrible problem generating a cursor over a dynamic screen display. If it's part of the image displayed, it has to be removed for reading and writing to the image displayed, so it is easier to find a hardware solution, where the device is given bitmap mask(s) and a location.

Comment: @WeatherVane So Sir is it impossible to get the cursor image or, can we create a copy of the cursor and then take its image ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  `XGetImage()` retrieves the drawable from the server.  The server takes all drawables and performs the composition to the screen hardware.  In this process, the cursor is a separate entity, possibly a hardware cursor.  If you want a to include the cursor in your image, you need to composite this into the image yourself.

Comment: Can you please tell how to composite the cursor in the image ?